Differing color behavior of Dolphin and other KDE apps outside plasma
I play around with dwm and would like to use dolphin as my file-manager. I want dolphin to use a specific coloring. So i copied the theme colors I've created using the system settings from ~/.local/share/color-schemes/*the-theme*.colors to ~/.config/kdeglobals.
This works for most KDE-apps like Kate and Okular, but Dolphin does not use some of the attributes. Here is a minimal config I've put to ~/.config/kdeglobals.
[Colors:View]
BackgroundAlternate=236,199,161
BackgroundNormal=236,199,161

[Colors:Window]
BackgroundAlternate=255,219,76
BackgroundNormal=197,158,124

The result i get for Dolphin and Kate looks like this:

Is there some other setting for Dolphin i have to add to the file?
Thanks to everyone who can provide some info!

I understand you are not using KDE. I could recommend you installing qt5ct or qt6ct, export it in your .bashrc file (export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qtXct) and add a qss file that gives you your desired output.
